# How to compare two post quantum digital signature schemes in terms of latency?

Tags: signature, provable-security, post-quantum-cryptography, security-definition, hash-signature

I want to compare two digital signature schemes of different nature. One is Hash-based (Winternitz one time signature scheme) and the other is lattice-based (Dilithium Crystals). What about be an academically accepted way to compare their latency and security?

Comment: You probably should first make sure they are solving the same problem, meaning convert the one-time signature scheme to a many-time signature scheme. I believe there is a generic way to do this with some merkle-tree type technique, but don't know details.

Comment: @Mark Can you please elaborate on the one-time signature scheme to many-time signature scheme? Also are there any examples that you can cite?

Comment: See [Lamport Signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_signature). I have heard that one can use Merkle Trees to get digital signatures from one-time signatures, but have never thought about the problem really.